# Which Hector will be most effective with a Distant Counter/Vantage build?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I have two Hectors, one will be inherited by someone else so they can get his Distant Counter skill.

**Hector #1: -Atk, +Spd:** I've had this Hector for a while, so he's got all the inherited skills, etc, no need for me to farm SP. My thinking is that this Speed boon will prevent Hector from being doubled as often or even occasionally get a double in, which would increase his survivability.

**Hector #2: +Def, -Res:** While this Hector doesn't suffer an Attack bane, I fear that the Resistance bane might put this Hector in a situation where he's not as tanky as my current one, due to his already-low Resistance being even further decreased.

As an aside, my current Hector is running Distant Counter + Vantage.

My current one already does pretty well at killing things, so I feel like I should keep him as is, and use #2 for inheriting, but I'm curious whether the effort required to bring Hector #2 up to speed will be worth it. Does the second Hector utilize my build effectively enough to warrant farming all the SP required to recreate this build or is the difference between these two negligible?

Comment: This is likely going to be opinionated. We would need far more information in order to make an informed choice; what team do you use, what do you usually face, what your play style is, etc. Without that, this can't be Good Subjective.

Comment: This question was fixed to no longer be an opinionated question. There was a specific build being asked about and the question was about the pros and cons of an experienced Hector versus a brand new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this ultimately will fall to your own judgment, there are objective pros and cons to each Hector:

- Your -ATK/+SPD Hector is missing out on one of his best stats, which makes Hector the monster that he is. Speed is definitely Hector's least useful stat, as he will almost always be doubled by enemies. However, due to the fact that this was the first Hector you summoned, he has the advantage in the skills he's inherited.
- Your second Hector, the one with the +DEF/-RES, would make a much better unit. Even though his attack isn't increased, *at least it isn't being harmed by his boon/bane spread*. While it may take a bit longer, you'd ultimately find the most success with this Hector.

Personally, for checking the viability of heroes, I look at their Gamepress page. [Here](https://fireemblem.gamepress.gg/hero/hector) is Hector's. The most useful stats for a boon on Hector are Attack or Defense, while the least useful stat (that is, the one that will do the least harm to have a penalty in) is Speed.

The build you're using is one of the "best" Hector builds, using a combination of his default Distant Counter with an inherited Vantage 3. With this build and a Defense boon, once Hector falls under 75% HP and activates Vantage, he will be able to strike anyone who attacks him first for 52 base damage and then tank any physical attacks with a whopping 40 Defense (more or less, depending on buffs/debuffs). These numbers are using your second Hector. Your first Hector would only hit for 49 base damage, which can most definitely be a game-changing difference.

However, the important thing to notice in both cases is that **Hector only attacks once**. Even with a Speed boon, Hector will only reach 28 Speed. He would need to be fighting an opponent with no more than 23 Speed to score a double.

From [this list of Heroes](https://fireemblem.gamepress.gg/heroes), the only heroes who would be doubled by Hector (this is assuming they do not also have a Speed boon) are Zephiel, Sophia, Berkut, Effie, Hawkeye, Henry, Leo, Lukas, Beruka, Reinhardt, Adult Tiki, and Wrys. For reference, even with a Speed boon, Hector will only be able to double 12 of the 168 currently available heroes. On the flip side, a 28 Speed Hector still suffers double attacks from **70** of the 168 heroes, again assuming a neutral Speed nature. Assuming a Speed boon on the opponent, this number rises to **108**.

---

An alternative solution to this would be to simply merge your old Hector into the new Hector. From personal experience, merging a hero with inherited skills into a hero with a blank slate of skills will unlock all skills the merged hero had unlocked. Your first Hector had Vantage 3 learned and equipped? Your Level 1+1 Hector now knows Vantage 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot! My current Hector does have Vantage 3. I was looking to get a second Hector to inherit `Distant Counter` on to an Ike - Brave Mercenary that I was lucky enough to get. I guess overall it would be worth the investment in time, to take your advice and keep the Hector +Def -Res, and merge the old one into Ike. I was simply worried the the `-res` on the new Hector might cause problems.

Comment: @Kenny yes, luckily Hector gets double SP from this mini Tempest Trial, so if you were lucky enough to get a Summer Tiki, you can use Tempest Trials to score massive SP for your new Hector.